# Does RABL's JSON output not conform to standard? Can it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

So I have a very simple rabl view that will support output for both xml and json (curr.rabl):

```
collection @currencies => "currencies"

attributes :code, :name
```

My rabl config:

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
    config.include_json_root = false
    config.include_child_root = false
    config.xml_options = { :skip_types => true, :camelize => :lower }
    config.include_xml_root = false
end
```

Output that rabl gives for xml and json:

XML:

```
<currencies>
<currency>
<code>AFN</code>
<name>Afghan Afghani</name>
</currency>
<currency>
<code>AFA</code>
<name>Afghanistan Afghani</name>
</currency>
</currencies>
```

JSON:

```
{
currencies: [
{
code: "AFN",
name: "Afghan Afghani"
},
{
code: "AFA",
name: "Afghanistan Afghani"
}]}
```

To me, **this is not correct**.  The JSON should look like the following according to what I've been reading:

```
{
currencies: {currency: [
{
code: "AFN",
name: "Afghan Afghani"
},
{
code: "AFA",
name: "Afghanistan Afghani"
} ] }
}
```

If I set the `config.include_child_root(/include_json_root) = true`, then I get the following (still not correct)

```
{
currencies: [
{
currency: {
code: "AFN",
name: "Afghan Afghani"
}
},
{
currency: {
code: "AFA",
name: "Afghanistan Afghani"
} } ] }
```

First, am I correct in my assumption that RABL is outputting the wrong json?
Second, is there a way to get RABL to do what I want for this view, as well as any other view that may have many nested child objects?

Comment: I always used the second form of what you have above.  You have a collection of currencies (an array) not a hash with one node (currency) that is an array.

Comment: I actually agree with you, but it seems like all the xml to JSON converters online do it the way I mentioned above. See [here](http://json.online-toolz.com/tools/xml-json-convertor.php), [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/) and [here](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html)

Comment: Both are valid JSON structures.  Do you know what client will be consuming the JSON?  The XML -> JSON conversions make sense, but that doesn't necessarily mean its what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear this is definitely **not standard**:

```
{
currencies: {currency: [
{
code: "AFN",
name: "Afghan Afghani"
},
{
code: "AFA",
name: "Afghanistan Afghani"
} ] }
}
```

Both forms RABL produces are standard. One without root and one with. This thing above doesn't make any sense, I have never seen any API act that way.

Answer (score 0):

I always used the second form of what you have above:

```
{
   currencies: [
   {
      currency: {  ... },
   },
   { 
      currency: { ... }
   }]
}
```

If you really want to do this:

```
{
   currencies: { currency: [ { ... }, { ... }] }
}
```

I think you can set include_json_root to false and use [custom nodes](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#custom-nodes) but it might get complicated.