# How to kill the array tag in this from/to xml of ActiveSupport?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/core_ext'

items = Hash.from_xml('<inventory><item><name>One</name></item><item><name>Two</name></item></inventory>')
print items.to_xml()
```

outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <inventory>
    <item type="array">
      <item>
        <name>One</name>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Two</name>
      </item>
    </item>
  </inventory>
</hash>
```

What I want is (`<item type="array">` tag killed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <inventory>
    <item>
      <name>One</name>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Two</name>
    </item>
</hash>
```

How to?

UPDATE, adding the `skip_types` option doesn't help much:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <inventory>
    <item>
      <item>
        <name>One</name>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Two</name>
      </item>
    </item>
  </inventory>
</hash>
```

Comment: items.to_xml(skip_types: true) would remove `type="array"`

Comment: Strange. I can't get skip_types working on ActiveRecord objects but it works fine on hashes. Might be a bug.

Comment: Here's a related question I answered a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560182/parsing-xml-to-hash-with-nori-and-nokogiri-with-undesired-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive the desired behavior with the `XmlSimple` gem:

```
gem install xml-simple
```

Then

```
require 'xmlsimple'

xml = '<inventory><item><name>One</name></item><item><name>Two</name></item></inventory>'

items = XmlSimple.xml_in(xml, KeepRoot: true)
#=> {"inventory"=>[{"item"=>[{"name"=>["One"]}, {"name"=>["Two"]}]}]}

puts XmlSimple.xml_out(items, KeepRoot: true)
# <inventory>
#   <item>
#     <name>One</name>
#   </item>
#   <item>
#     <name>Two</name>
#   </item>
# </inventory>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be general enough, but doing this will result in having the source XML back:

```
items = Hash.from_xml('<inventory><item><name>One</name></item><item><name>Two</name></item></inventory>')
print items['inventory']['item'].to_xml(root: 'inventory', 
  children: 'item', skip_types: true)
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# <inventory>
#   <item>
#     <name>One</name>
#   </item>
#   <item>
#     <name>Two</name>
#   </item>
# </inventory>
```